# How do I get started with the Cthulhu mythos?

Tags: reading-order, h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu

Having encountered a number of references to Cthulhu in various places over the years, I would like to explore the various works based in the Cthulhu mythos. Out of curiosity, I had read *[The Call of Cthulhu](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Call_of_Cthulhu)* some time ago, but I don't know much about Lovecraft's other works or where to go next. It's my understanding that other authors have also contributed to the Cthulhu mythos and that it has a number of short stories as well.

How would you recommend going about exploring this?

Given so many short stories, I hope answerers will recommend anthologies which collectively include all the stories they recommend.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but there's a similar question on [Sci-fi and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/whats-the-best-order-to-read-hp-lovecrafts-novels)

Comment: @Gallifreian of course it does, thanks! But I'll keep this one, I'd like to get some anthology recommendations and some recommendations for other authors using Cthulhu

Comment: `other authors using Cthulhu` - [way ahead of you](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25171/in-what-order-should-i-read-the-extended-cthulhu-mythos). Though this one is not as detailed as the H. P. Lovecraft's.

Comment: @Gallifreian that is an understatement

Answer (score 5):

To start getting involved, I would read the original author's works before moving onto anyone else.

*The Complete Works of H.P. Lovecraft* frequently appears as a free download for Kindle.  If you prefer the printed word, it is available in paperback.

The stories appear in the anthology in an order that is not the chronological published order.  However, reading them in the order as presented is a perfectly good way of getting into the mythos.

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://arkhamarchivist.com/free-complete-lovecraft-ebook-nook-kindle/? If not, can you specify the publisher?

Comment: @muru:  It was this one https://www.amazon.co.uk/H-P-Lovecraft-Complete-Fiction-ebook/dp/B01HUIFYQ4/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1484906513&sr=1-1&keywords=lovecraft

Comment: *The Complete Works of Lovecraft* is also available free as a PDF on [this blog](https://maggiemcneill.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/the-complete-works-of-h-p-lovecraft.pdf).

Comment: I haven't read most of these stories, but my impression was most of them are unrelated to Cthlulhu.  Can you be more specific about which stories one should start reading?